# WCF in VB.net named pipe issue

Tags: .net, wcf

I am trying to use the WCF Test Client to test my WCF Service, here is my app.config.  This works great, but when I change the baseAddress to "net.pipe://localhost/VSWCFPipe", it no longer works.  What is the correct way to change the baseAddress to the named pipe?  I was wanting to use only net.pipe, since this is for IPC on a local computer only.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="WCFServiceBehavior"
        name="WCFEngineService.WCFService">
        <clear />
        <endpoint address="mex" binding="mexHttpBinding" contract="IMetadataExchange"
          listenUriMode="Explicit">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost" />
            <certificateReference storeName="My" storeLocation="LocalMachine"
              x509FindType="FindBySubjectDistinguishedName" />
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
        <endpoint address="net.pipe://localhost/VSWCFPipe" binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
          bindingConfiguration="" contract="WCFEngineService.IWCF" />
        <host>
          <baseAddresses>
            <add baseAddress="http://localhost:8888/WCFEngineService/Service" />
          </baseAddresses>
        </host>
      </service>
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="WCFServiceBehavior">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
          <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="False"/>
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
  </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you missed to add **net.pipe** protocol in your enabled protocol list. Please go through the below steps and confirm whether the settings are correct or not.

1. Go to IIS (type **inetmgr** in run window)
2. Select and right click of your service from left pane.
3. Select Manage Application ----> Advance Settings menu from right click context menu.
4. In Advanced Settings window select **Enabled Protocol** property.
5. By default http protocol will be added. Add **net.pipe** by a comma separator . eg: **http,net.pipe**

Comment: Hi, thank you for the help!  I started IIS, but the service does not appear in the left pane.  Also, do I need net.tcp?  I am trying to only use named pipes.  Thank you.

Comment: @DannyBoy sorry that was a typo. You need to mention net.pipe instead of net.tcp. Please refer below link to understand how to host WCF service in IIS http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733766.aspx